# Add multiple response in Watson chatbot using Java

Tags: java, ibm-watson

I am creating a Watson chatbot using Java platform. But I am unable to create multiple response. How to use this option in code selection_policy = "multiline"?

Answer (score 0):

With version 6.5.1 of the SDK, you can add this to the generic output.
Assuming you have the text values in a JSONArray:

```
DialogNodeOutputGeneric generic = new DialogNodeOutputGeneric();
    List<DialogNodeOutputTextValuesElement> textValues= new 
ArrayList<DialogNodeOutputTextValuesElement>();    
JsonArray valuesAsJson = <YOU SHOULD HAVE THIS Populated>;
for (int i = 0; i < valuesAsJson.size(); i++) {
    JsonElement valueAsJson=valuesAsJson.get(i);
    DialogNodeOutputTextValuesElement textResponse= new DialogNodeOutputTextValuesElement();
    textResponse.setText(valueAsJson.getAsJsonObject().get("text").getAsString());
                textValues.add(textResponse);
}
generic.setResponseType(ResponseType.TEXT);
generic.setSelectionPolicy(SelectionPolicy.MULTILINE);
generic.setValues(textValues);
```

I did not have to do anything to set the response variations to *sequential* .
But the SDK allows for other options like MULTILINE above...